# SQL statement in Netbeans controller

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to use an update SQL statement in my Netbeans controller class.

Method in controller:

```
public String verify(){
String result = "failed";
int authcode = staffBean.getVerifyCodeByName(getLoginUserName());
if ( code==authcode){

    result ="success";
//add an update SQL statement
}

else{

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Code does not match!");
}
return result;
}
```

Anyone know whats the syntax for it? Or is it not possible to do it in here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string updateSql = "UPDATE Employees " + "SET LastName = @LastName " + "WHERE FirstName = @FirstName";             
SqlCommand UpdateCmd = new SqlCommand(updateSql, thisConnection);              
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10, "FirstName");                   
UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20, "LastName");
UpdateCmd.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = "Wade";            
UpdateCmd.Parameters["@LastName"].Value = "Harvey";            
UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```